# Case insensitive indexOfObject for NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Is there an easy way to do a case insensitive lookup in an NSArray of NSStrings?  Reference for NSArray mentions sorting case insensitively but nothing about lookup.

I can easily write my own fn to do it but would like to know if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in way to do this. However, it would be trivial to write a category on NSArray which does this:

```
@interface NSArray (CaseInsensitiveIndexing)
- (NSUInteger)indexOfCaseInsensitiveString:(NSString *)aString;
@end

@implementation NSArray (CaseInsensitiveIndexing)

- (NSUInteger)indexOfCaseInsensitiveString:(NSString *)aString {
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    for (NSString *object in self) {
        if ([object caseInsensitiveCompare:aString] == NSOrderedSame) {
            return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return NSNotFound;
}   

@end
```

Of course, you'd probably want to do a bit of type checking to make sure the array's items actually *are* NSStrings before you call `-caseInsensitiveCompare:`, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  That's pretty much what I did, but just in a local function.  I'm pretty new to ObjC so pardon my ignorance, but is there any advantage to how you've iterated the array vs a simple "for (NSUInteger i=0; i<self.count; i++) ... [self objectAtIndex:i]"??

Comment: No, both approaches are fine. I tend to do things this way, since certain compilers (or even certain modes of certain compilers) don't allow the variable declaration within the for loop. Since you can never be sure what flags people are passing to their compilers, I try to make sure that any code I post here should compile for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

questioner ,

it's an excellent idea of writing a category in NSArray to do this . 
it helped me a lot in my app.
However there's a pretty much easier way to do the this instead 
of iterating the array.

---

```
@interface NSArray (CaseInsensitiveIndexing)
- (NSUInteger)indexOfCaseInsensitiveString:(NSString *)aString;
@end

@implementation NSArray (CaseInsensitiveIndexing)

- (NSUInteger)indexOfCaseInsensitiveString:(NSString *)aString 
{
   return [self indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
   { 
       return [[obj lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[aString lowercaseString]]; 
   }];
}   

@end
```

---

Note :indexOfObjectPassingTest works with IOS 4.0 only

Answer (score 1):

No custom category needed:

```
[myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return (BOOL)([obj caseInsensitiveCompare:term] == NSOrderedSame);
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but you should be able to do this by filtering the array with an NSPredicate.