# video format validation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I perform video format validation in iOS. There are a series of documents being downloaded from the server. It can be of any type(pdf,xls,doc,png,.mp4,.mov,.wmv,.flv,etc,etc). Before downloading, I need to show a pop up if the video format is not supported in iPhone. Do I have to manually put if conditions for each of them and check or is there any simple way to do this? I know iOS does not support wmv,flv,etc. Basically I need to implement this validation check in objective C

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the video data to validate, then I guess all your can do is validate that the file format is supported based on the file extension:

```
NSArray *supportedExtensions = @"[ @"mov", @"mp4", ... ];
NSURL *videoURL = ...;
NSString *extension = [videoURL pathExtension];
BOOL supported = [supportedExtensions indexOfObject:extension] != NSNotFound;
if (supported) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Note: you probably want to use [a case-insensitive version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297299/case-insensitive-indexofobject-for-nsarray) of that `indexOfObject`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. But supportedExtensions array  cannot just have video format extensions. The [url pathExtension] can be anything like pdf,doc,xls,png,jpg,txt,etc. Hence, I guess we cannot hardcode values into supportedExtensions array. The path is dynamic here. It's just that when the path is a video format extension and not supported in iPhone I need to display an alert message. Rest all the path extensions should pass the validation.